# Methods for approximating the projection onto a unit $\ell^p$ ball

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, projection

Let $p\in\left[1,+\infty\right]$. I am curious if there are methods for computing (or approximating) the orthogonal projection onto the unit ball of the [$\ell^p$ norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#General_%E2%84%93p-space), i.e., given any $x$ in a Euclidean space $(\mathcal{X}, \|\cdot\|_2)$, compute
$$
\underset{{\substack{y\in\mathcal{X}\\\|y\|_p\leq 1}}}{\textrm{Argmin}} \;\;\|x-y\|_2.
\tag{$*$}
$$
I know this is possible in closed-form for $p=1$, $p=2$, and $p=\infty$. However, my understanding is that closed-form solutions for general $p\in\left[1,+\infty\right]$ is an open question (please let me know if this has been solved!).

However, are there efficient methods of *approximating* a solution to ($*$)? As pointed out in the comments, some standard convex optimization tools could be used for this. If these tools are the most efficient (in some sense of the word), that would be great; however, are there also methods designed specifically for solving ($*$)?

Comment: I guess this can be handled using standard convex optimization algorithms. I suppose you’re asking about methods that in some way exploit the structure of this particular problem?

Comment: @DavidM. Ideally, yes. However, I would be interested to know what folks view as the most "efficient" algorithm for this estimation (and, if it is just an out-of-the-box algorithm, that would be fine).